# SwiftUI: How do you dismiss a sheet and launch a different sheet from ContentView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

For my app, I have a welcome screen that intro's what the app does and allows the user to create their first item. When the user clicks the button I'd like to dismiss the 'welcomeScreen' sheet and and then launch the 'newRemindr' sheet.

I tried to achieve this by creating an observable object with an 'addNewTrigger' boolean set to false. When I click the Add New Reminder button on the welcomeScreen, the button's action causes the welcomeScreen to dismiss and toggles the 'addNewTrigger' boolean to True. (I've verified this is working with Print Statements). However content view is listening to that same observed object to launch the 'newRemindr' sheet but that action doesn't seem to be working.

Can somebody please take a look at the code and see where I am going wrong? Or suggest an alternative that can provide the type of functionality.

I really appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Code Below...

**welcomeScreen:**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct welcomeScreen: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

@ObservedObject var addNewReminder = showAddScreen()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack (alignment: .center) {

            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.white, Color.gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Image("Ellipse2")
                .offset(y: -475)

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Welcome to")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Image("RemindrLogoWhite")
                Spacer()
                Text("What is remindr?")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.bottom, 25)
                Text("Remindr is a simple app designed to help you schedule random reminders with the goal of clearing your mind.\n\nRemind yourself to check in with your body, set up positive affirmations, set your intentions; Whatever it is, the power is up to you.")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                    .padding(.bottom, 25)
                Text("Click below to get started:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)

                // Add New Reminder Button
                Button(action: {
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    print("Add Reminder Button from Welcome Screen is Tapped")
                    self.addNewReminder.addNewTrigger.toggle()
                    print("var addNewTrigger has been changed to \(self.addNewReminder.addNewTrigger)")
                }) {
                    Image("addButton")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                }.padding(.bottom, 25)

                Spacer()

            } .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                     maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .automatic)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }))
    }
  }
}
```

**ContentView:**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class showAddScreen: ObservableObject {
@Published var addNewTrigger = false
}

struct ContentView: View {


@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(entity: ReminderEntity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ReminderEntity.dateCreated, ascending: false)])
var reminder: FetchedResults<ReminderEntity>

// Sheet Control
@ObservedObject var addNewReminder = showAddScreen()
//@State private var showingAddScreen = false
@State var showWelcomeScreen = false
    
let emojiList = EmojiList()

//Toggle Control
@State var notifyOn = true

// Save Items Function
func saveItems() {
    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

// Delete Item Function
func deleteItem(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    let source = indexSet.first!
    let listItem = reminder[source]
    moc.delete(listItem)
}

// View Controller
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                
                // List View
                List {
                    ForEach(reminder, id: \.self) { notification in
                        NavigationLink(destination: editRemindr(reminder: notification,
                                                                notifyOn: notification.notifyOn,
                                                                emojiChoice: Int(notification.emojiChoice),
                                                                notification: notification.notification ?? "unknown",
                                                                notes: notification.notes ?? "unknown")) {
                            // Text within List View
                            HStack {
                                // MARK: TODO
                                //Toggle("NotifyOn", isOn: self.$notifyOn)
                                //    .labelsHidden() // Hides the label/title
                                Text("\(self.emojiList.emojis[Int(notification.emojiChoice)]) \(notification.notification!)")
                            } 
                        }
                    } 
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                    }.lineLimit(1)
                    
                    // Navigation Items
                    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(
                        leading:
                        HStack {
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showWelcomeScreen.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .regular))
                            }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                            
                            // Positioning Remindr Logo on Navigation
                            Image("remindrLogoSmall")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                //.frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                                .padding(.leading, 83)
                                .padding(.top, -10)
                        },
                        
                        // Global Settings Navigation Item
                        trailing: NavigationLink(destination: globalSettings()){
                            Image("settings")
                                .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))
                        }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                )
                
                // Add New Reminder Button
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { self.addNewReminder.addNewTrigger.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image("addButton")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $addNewReminder.addNewTrigger) {
                        
                        newRemindr().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }  .sheet(isPresented: $showWelcomeScreen) {
            welcomeScreen()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined your .sheet modifiers. you can't declare 2 .sheet modifiers on top of one view, they should be on top of two different views. (Buttons, Texts, ... are views too)

Comment: your sheets are still placed badly. this a bug which has not been resolved since last year, so this is not your fault. move `.sheet(isPresented: $showWelcomeScreen) {
            welcomeScreen()
        }` to above the comment `// Add New Reminder Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what I see is you use *different* observable objects in both views, but should use same, so changes made in one view be available for second view as well.

Se here is a way to solve this

```
struct welcomeScreen: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

@ObservedObject var addNewReminder: showAddScreen // << declare to be injected

// ... other code
```

and in `ContentView`

```
}  .sheet(isPresented: $showWelcomeScreen) {
    welcomeScreen(addNewReminder: self.addNewReminder)    // << inject !!
}
```

**Alternate:** you can remove `addNewReminder` from `welcomeScreen` and work with it only in `ContentView` by activating on welcome sheet dismiss, like

```
}  .sheet(isPresented: $showWelcomeScreen, onDismiss: {
              // it is better to show second sheet with delay to give chance
              // for first one to animate closing to the end
              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                 self.addNewReminder.addNewTrigger.toggle()
              }
          }
   ) {
    welcomeScreen()
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's good to see I was on the right track. Thanks so much for your help.