# How to call method from another viewModel when sheet dismiss in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having view and viewModel. I am navigating to sheet from view and doing few things and dismissing it, as soon as i dismiss sheet i want to call one method in viewModel.

In **FirstView** presenting sheet like

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showAddView) {
    AddView(viewModel: AddViewModel(showAddView: $showAddView))
 }
```

In **FirstViewModel** i want to call method on sheet dismiss

```
func update() {
   print("I get called")
   //some logic
}
```

in action sheet **AddView**

```
doing some logic and dismissing
```

Please help how should i call method.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530803/swiftui-how-do-you-dismiss-a-sheet-and-launch-a-different-sheet-from-contentvie) help?

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to know when the view was dismissed, you can observe changes to `showAddView` like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showAddView) {
    AddView(viewModel: AddViewModel(showAddView: $showAddView))
}
.onChange(of: showAddView) { newValue 
    guard !newValue else { return }
    // Will be executed when newValue changes to false
    // I think it will also be called the first time your view is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A great solution for this is to pass a function as an argument. The general idea here is to match your function signature to get it to allow it. So on your FirstViewModel you've got your method `update()` you can pass that to the `AddView()` as a property of the object by doing something like this. Also this is particularly useful if you've got a value in your `AddView` that needs to be used in your `update` function.

#### First View Model

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showAddView) {
    AddView(viewModel: AddViewModel(showAddView: $showAddView), update: update)
}
```

#### AddView

Simply add a property to hold the passed function. Then call it on dismiss.

```
{
    let update: () -> ()
    // The rest of your view

    //Close Button
    Button(action {
        self.update()   
    }, label(...
}
```

#### What is a function signature?

Suppose your update function is this.

```
func update(someInt: Int) {
    //Do Something
}
```

You can match the signature by creating a property like this.

- `let someUpdateFunc: (Int) -> ()`
- The syntax is `name: -> (Type) -> (Return Type)`
- It's also possible to have multiple types as an argument. For example
- `let someOtherFunc: (Int, String) -> ()`

Answer (score 0):

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $shouldAddView, onDismiss: viewModel.update) { ... }
```